# rvest to ignore urls don't exist and move on with scraping

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am new to web scraping and rvest package. What I want to accomplish is to scape the news content from below website: http://www.xwlbo.com/31035.html

I noticed there is pattern for historical news with the number index, however I figured out later that the number index is random with no explicit rules therefore, there might be webpages that don't exist and I got an error of `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.`. How can I ignore the empty webpages and move on with webpages that do exist.

Here is what I came up so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="chinese")

web_index_number <- 4058:31106

urls <- str_c("http://www.xwlbo.com/",web_index_number,".html")



news_collect <- function(x){
  webpage <- read_html(x)
  wp_title <- html_node(webpage,'h2') %>% 
   html_text()
wp_content <- html_nodes(webpage,'p , a , h2') %>% 
   html_text()
len <- length(wp_content)-3
wp_content <- wp_content[1:len]
wp_title <- rep(wp_title,len)
news <- data.frame(wp_title,wp_content)}

news_collection <- map_df(urls,news_collect)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trycatch structure where you try to execute the code starting with *news_collect*. If *read_html(x)* fails you can just write in the error code to print the error and return NULL.